# ntp и ntpdate в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ntp

После обновления до Ubuntu 16.04 у меня начались проблемы с ntp.

1. Если я ставлю ntpdate и ntp вместе, то после перезагрузки компьютера, у меня время показывается неправильно(совсем ничего не исправляет). А `service ntp status` показывает следующее:

> ntp.service - LSB: Start NTP daemon    Loaded: loaded
>   (/etc/init.d/ntp; bad; vendor preset: enabled)    Active: inactive
>   (dead)
>        Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8) апр 24 20:43:50 hp systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start NTP daemon. апр 24 20:43:51 hp
>   systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start NTP daemon. апр 24 20:43:52 hp
>   systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start NTP daemon.

2. Если удалить пакет ntpdate, то сам ntp запускается нормально, но время исправляется только через секунд 15, после того как система стартовала.

Как сделать так, чтобы ntpdate и ntp работали вместе и время при запуске было сразу правильное?

Comment: *время исправляется* — у вас проблемы с аппаратными часами?

Comment: У меня еще параллельно стоит windows, которые аппаратные часы конвертирует по своему, в отличие от Unix. Поэтому, если в одной ОС нормально, то в другой нет. Поэтому я решил, что в Ubuntu буду время ставить с помощью  ntp. В 15.10 все работало нормально, сейчас почему ntp автоматически не запускается, я никак не пойму. Точнее почему ntpdata мешает ему запускаться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

проблема ваша, выходит в том, что *ms/windows* сохраняет в аппаратных часах локальное время, а *gnu/linux*, как и положено, сохраняет время в [*utc*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F).

выхода два:

1. [настроить *ms/windows*](https://superuser.com/a/185780/454489), чтобы она сохраняла время, как и положено, в *utc*.
2. [настроить *ubuntu*](https://askubuntu.com/a/521177/416190), чтобы она сохраняла локальное время в аппаратных часах (добавить строку `UTC=no` в файл `/etc/default/rcS`).

Comment: Да, вы правы. После того, как поправил /etc/default/rcS, время сразу грузится правильно, но вот ntp по прежнему не запускается, если стоит ntpdate. Пришлось ntpdate снести, чтобы ntp работало.